# Equivalent phrasing to the conclusion to the a quotient group related question.

Tags: group-theory

The conclusion to the following question:

> Let $G$ be an abelian group and $T$ its torsion subgroup.  Prove that $G/T$ has no nonidentity elements of finite order

Is the wording the same as the following:

> Every nonzero element of the quotient group $G/T$ has infinite order.

I struggle with understanding the use of double negatives in english. Hence my question.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't know nothing about the subtleties of double negatives in English :) But in this instance "$G/T$ has no nonidentity elements of finite order" is equivalent to "all nonidentity elements of $G/T$ have infinite order", and zero is the identity element, so yes, the two statements are equivalent.

Comment: @DerekHolt ok ok, thank you for clarifying it for me.